# Recognize text within MS Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

Question: Why is the text as described below not recognized in the first paragraph within the IF statement?  I just started looking at MS Word VBA code this week. I understand some basic programming in MS Excel, but this has me perplexed.

The entire first paragraph is "Sample Text" in the active document (for this sample). I'm writing this in a simple way, so I can understand the process. Thanks.

```vb
Sub ParagraphNo1()
    Dim Para1 As Paragraph
    Set Para1 = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1)
    If Para1.Range.Text = "Sample Text" Then
       MsgBox "Yes, that is correct...it is Sample Text." 'It fails to recognize Sample Text. I did not find a hidden space.
    End If
    
    MsgBox Para1.Range.Text
    'But the message box above describes it as Sample Text (exactly as above), but it is not recognized within the If Statement.
    
End Sub
```

If I change it to:

```vb
If Para1.Range.Text <> "Sample Text" Then
   MsgBox "Yes, that is correct...it is not Sample Text." 'This tells me it recognizes something different.
End If
```

I tried it with different text also, but I had the same problem. I tried also to add a blank space at the end, but that was no help either.

Comment: A bit hard to help without seeing the entire picture. Why don’t you write Para1.Range.Text out to the immediate window so you can see exactly what it looks like? Or, throw a breakpoint in so you can analyze.

Comment: `Para1.Range.Text` includes the "end of paragraph" character Chr(13) (`vbCr`) but that's not going to be obvious when you use Msgbox.   `MsgBox "<" & Para1.Range.Text & ">"` makes it a little more obvious.

Comment: Thank you both for replying.  When I added Chr(13) that solved it, so it could be recognized wtihin the IF Statement.

Comment: Now that I found that out (about vbCr), I'm gong to take it further.  My actual code is much more complicated.  I wrote the sample that way on purpose, to make it simple. This is my first post using Stack Overflow, so I hope I did all of this right for you all. I did also use "selection" and it did look different (when it selected the text).  It was like a space was there at the end but I couldn't see it.  Thank you both again.

Comment: While working this out you might find it easier if you show hidden characters (toggle using `Ctr+*` / `Ctrl+Shift+8`)